# Regex and Input validation in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to validate an input with regex to make sure the input is something like: `0,7`

0 being the lowest number

7 being the highest number

they need to be separated with and ","

I've tried using

```
re.match("[0-7,0-7]", input):
```

No luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do:

```
re.match("[0-7],[0-7]$", input):
```

In Regex, `[...]` is a character set.  This means that, in your original pattern, you were looking for a *single* character that is either a comma or a digit in the range of 0 to 7.  Adding `0-7` twice does nothing.

Also, I don't know what `input` is, but if it is a variable, then you should change its name.  Having a variable named `input` overshadows the built-in.

If `input` *is* the built-in though, then you need to invoke it by adding `()` at the end:

```
re.match("[0-7],[0-7]$", input()):
```

Comment: -1. You need anchor at the end. `re.match("[0-7],[0-7]", "5,69")` will return a match.

Answer (score 1):

```
import http.cookiejar
class MyCookiePolicy(http.cookiejar.DefaultCookiePolicy):
    def set_ok(self, cookie, request):
        if not http.cookiejar.DefaultCookiePolicy.set_ok(self, cookie, request):
            return False
        if i_dont_want_to_store_this_cookie(cookie):
            return False
        return True
Rx .|. Racoon =< c
```

Comment: Revert sve location bin host implementing code